# How to extract characters from a string but only after a certain phrase is seen?

Tags: javascript

hopefully my question makes sense.

So I am trying to make it so that my program would take in a string for example "Hello my name is John, I like apples." and I want my program to respond with everything after the comma so it would return " I like apples.". How would I go about doing this? I know that I need to make my program look for the comma, but I don't know how to make it so that it only takes the text that comes after the comma. I guess I am trying to splice everything before the comma so I'm just left with everything else, hopefully that makes sense!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `split`:

```
var text = "Hello my name is John, I like apples.";
var bits = text.split(',');
var myText = bits[1];
```

Comment: you may have many , and need to join again all pieces except the [0]...